# Find Column Header based on criteria from an array

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, header, index-match

I want to return the value of the header based on criteria that can be found in the array

Example: If I put C4 on cell I2, C4 is found at cell D4 on the left table therefore it should return value **Header 4** since it is the header of that column

[image]

Comment: Have a look at these solutions for multiple criteria [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76644962).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `J2`

```
=CONCAT(REPT(A1:F1,N(I2=A2:F5)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `J3`

```
=FILTER(A1:F1,BYCOL(A2:F5=I2,LAMBDA(x,OR(x))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `J4`

```
="Header "&AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$F$1)/($A$2:$F$5=I2),1)
```

---

Comment: For **3rd One** : You can wrap within `INDEX()` if the header is always different --> `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:F1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$F$1)/($A$2:$F$5=I2),1)),"")`

Comment: Nice one on the CONCAT/REPT

Answer (score 2):

### Match Column, Return Header

```
=LET(data,A1:F5,c,I2,e,"",
    h,TAKE(data,1),d,TOCOL(DROP(data,1)),
IFERROR(INDEX(h,,MOD((XMATCH(c,d)-1),COLUMNS(h))+1),e))
```

[image]