# Excel- find an item in an array and return the top column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of information by columns.  I have values to look up within the table but I am unable to get the column heading as a result.

Tried both LOOKUP, Match and Index.  Not sure what I want can be done since the lookup is throughout the entire table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSb8j.png)

Comment: Please put the input data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) and provide the expected output for your input data. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Column Header based on criteria from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359879/find-column-header-based-on-criteria-from-an-array)

Comment: Please do some research the community all these queries are solved priorly.

Answer (score 2):

### Match Column, Return Header (Multiple Results)

- It's basically the same as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76360238), noticed by Mayukh Bhattacharya in your comments, the only difference being that it spills multiple matching results achieved by using the `BYROW` function.

[image]

```
=LET(lcRange,A2:A11,sTable,D1:F4,NoMatch,"Nope",
    sh,TAKE(sTable,1),sd,TOCOL(DROP(sTable,1)),sCols,COLUMNS(sh),
BYROW(lcRange,LAMBDA(r,
    IFERROR(INDEX(sh,,MOD((XMATCH(r,sd)-1),sCols)+1),NoMatch))))
```

**Input Variables**

```
lcRange - Lookup (Single) Column Range
sTable  - Source Table
NoMatch - If No Match Is Found
```

**Other Variables**

```
sh      - Source Headers
sd      - Source Data
sCols   - Number of Source Columns
r       - Each Lookup Cell (Row) Value
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to resolve this, I have already answered few **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359903/8162520)**

Alternatives includes Non-MS365 Versions as well.

---

[image]

---

Using <kbd>BYROW( )</kbd>, <kbd>CONCAT( )</kbd> & <kbd>REPT( )</kbd>

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=BYROW(A2:A16,LAMBDA(x,CONCAT(REPT(I2:S2,x=I3:S17))))
```

---

Comment: To cover for duplicates, you could return multiple delimited matches by replacing `CONCAT(REPT(I2:S2,x=I3:S17))` with e.g. `TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT(I2:S2,x=I3:S17))`.

Comment: Don't think there will be duplicates. Because those are Stock Tickers for each kind of a category so having chances of duplicates is almost 0, I believe.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to point out how flexible your solution is. Someone else might need it. I would need to change quite a lot to make it happen in my solution since it only returns the first match looking by rows.

Comment: Sir, I had no intention to answer this question posted only since I saw an answer here, however it should have been closed tagged as duplicate.

Comment: IMO, it's debatable but I linked this (OP's) post to the other anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I am not sure a stock belongs to just one ETF (related to industry sectors), the columns names represents ETFs, as per my understanding, now you make me doubt if that is the case in the stock market. Both solutions are great! I added mine, I think it works better for a large dataset, worth to verify it.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya similar idea using `CONCAT` as follows: `=BYROW(A2:A16,LAMBDA(x, CONCAT(IF(I3:S17=x,I2:S2,""))))`, `IF` is more intuitive to understand than `REPT` in this case in my opinion.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya and `REPT` does an unnecessary cast to string, **not relevant** for this case, because the header are texts. It can be avoided with the formula in my previous comment, since it doesn't transform the header values. In general I would say it is better not transform the data unless it is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here another alternative, using @VBasic2008's sample data:

```
=BYROW(E2:E11,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(@TOCOL(IF(A2:C4=x,A1:C1,NA()),2),"Not Found")))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`@`-operator is used in case of duplicated values. In that case, it returns the first column header value found. `IFERROR` is used just in case the value was not found. `TOCOL` function is very efficient, so it would be suitable for a large dataset too.

If you want to return all the headers in case of duplicated values, then use the following:

```
=BYROW(E2:E11,LAMBDA(x, 
 IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,TOCOL(IF(A2:C4=x,A1:C1,NA()),2)),"Not Found")))
```

In case of non-duplicated values, the follow works too:

```
=BYROW(E2:E11,LAMBDA(x,LET(z,CONCAT(IF(A2:C4=x,A1:C1,"")),
 IF(z="","Not Found",z))))
```

The `IF` condition is added to treat the case of not found. Similar idea used by @MayukhBhattacharya. If you don't want to handle this case, it results in a shorter approach:

```
=BYROW(E2:E11,LAMBDA(x,CONCAT(IF(A2:C4=x,A1:C1,""))))
```